# Redis Sentinel for Windows

Tags: redis, sentinel

I'm successfully using Redis for Windows (2.6.8-pre2) in a master slave setup. However, I need to provide some automated failover capability, and it appears the sentinel is the most popular choice. When I run redis in sentinel mode the sentinel connects, but it always thinks the master is down. Also, when I run the sentinel master command it reports that there are 0 slaves (not true) and that there are no other sentinels (again, not true). So it's like it connects to the master, but not correctly.

Has anyone else seen this issue on Windows and, more importantly, is anyone successfully using sentinel in a windows environment? Any help or direction at all is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use this:

- 1 master node redis server 1 slave node redis server
- List item 3 redis sentinels with a quorum of 2

It's so important have more than have 3 sentinels to get a odd quorum. 
I made this configuration in Windows 7 and it's working well.

Example of sentinel conf:

```
port 20001
logfile "sentinel1.log"

sentinel monitor shard1 127.0.0.1 16379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds shard1 5000
sentinel failover-timeout shard1 30000
```